# Puzzling Map Type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to build a Map-like class that maps the keys of one type to the keys of another. A simple solution would be to just create a `Map<keyof A, keyof B>` and call it done. But this does not check that the member type of each key matches in both `A` and `B`.

I have the following class started, and I was hoping to do some type assertion that `T` is not `never`.

```
class KeyMap<A, B> {
  private mapping = new Map<keyof A, keyof B>();

  add<KA extends keyof A, KB extends keyof B, T = A[KA] & B[KB]>(
    a: KA,
    b: KB
  ): void {
    this.mapping.set(a, b);
  }
}
```

I do not know if this is even possible, but I can imagine this would be a useful map to have.

To take a step back, I am trying to build a reusable utility that will convert between `A` and `B` in a type-safe way, validating that all of the member types match. If there is a better way to do this, then I'd be open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside your final "is there a better way to do this" question, this is how I'd make `add()` require that the `b` parameter be restricted to just keys from `B` where the corresponding property in `A` from the `a` parameter has some overlap (e.g., `A[KA] & B[KB]` is not `never`):

```
type KeysWithOverlap<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: (T[K] & V) extends never ? never : K }[keyof T];

class KeyMap<A, B> {
    private mapping = new Map<keyof A, keyof B>();

    add<KA extends keyof A, KB extends KeysWithOverlap<B, A[KA]>>(
        a: KA,
        b: KB
    ): void {
        this.mapping.set(a, b);
    }
}
```

`KeysWithOverlap<T, V>` takes a type `T` and a value type `V` and returns all the keys of `T` whose properties have some overlap with `V`.  Then all we do is constrain `KB` not to `keyof B` but to `KeysWithOverlap<B, A[KA]>`.  Let's see how it works:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b: 3;
    c: boolean;
}

interface Bar {
    d: "str";
    e: number;
    f: boolean;
}

const km = new KeyMap<Foo, Bar>();
km.add("a", "e"); // error! e is not assignable to d
km.add("a", "d"); // okay
km.add("b", "e"); // okay
km.add("c", "f"); // okay
```

Note how there is an error when you try to call `add("a", "e")`, since `string` and `number` have no overlap.  The other calls work because the types are compatible.

---

So is there a better way to do this?

Maybe; "no overlap" might not be strict enough; are you looking for types where you can *read* an `A[KA]` from a `B[KB]`?  Or ones where you an *write* one?  Given the `Foo` and `Bar` types above, what problems would happen if you mapped a `Foo` to/from a `Bar`, since `Bar["d"]` only accepts the specific string `"str"`, you'd need to be careful if you try to just copy the `"a"` property of a `Foo` to it.

If I were to try making a general property-mapping function, I'd probably do it where the specific key mapping were represented in the type system, e.g., `declare function convert<T, M extends {[K in keyof T]: PropertyKey}>(obj: T, keyMap: M): ConvertKeys<T, M>;` for a suitable definition of `ConvertKeys`.  I can maybe write that, but that would be more effort and starts straying from what I consider the main point of this question.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcDqBLYALA8gNwgJwBsBDMAHgBUAaKANQD4oBeKAbygG0YoUA7KAa3gB7AGZRyAXQC0AfgBcUABTlOEqADJaASigQAHsAg8AJgig8IuPFBnnL+KAq4BfdoJCjxEgNwBYAFABAMbECGZwIACyJKQAgtQAQgwsAVBpUGB4KNhEhlAAtiRgvADmTHYA7lDRZO6e8QLCYkmKWn6B-ulQRMbGpDCxugZGpo0eYg0wCUOGJuHwyGhYVsRkCdSxnLESdHSKqV3pRE7xB4dQAEZOCWdQWgrYQijGrLddGCgIAHSFYMU8JS+CAgwEURGoFzat2cARhHV4hjwIiIQWgADEhEJXp0jgoEMAsgD2l0rlAAMzE9JBBQXTEECBEHjtOEBBH4ZGoqAJIjWFI4tLGBQAInxeCFlLSEAUPAArvkLvgJVARDS6QymbCAsEhDx8QJ8uULFUIjVSBihIkeXsof5+Pkvj1jIohUQhdQhRAhW0oAB6H26PB4IR4ACEum4Zh4QmA3TCKBKPCIF3pUGAWOMATtDt6ztd7uMXu8vv9Qn4RBAmftjudFzdUA9heLUFL5cr2adQqCdaFIkbfubZYr-iAA)

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head, this is perfect! The problem I'm really trying to solve is maintaining two similar model classes, one for a TypeORM entity, and the other an auto-generated model interface from OpenAPI generator. There are numerous reasons I wouldn't want to use the same class/interface for both, but I think the utility you outlined will do just what I need.

Comment: Although @jcalz I would like to be able to enforce that the types are exactly the same, i.e. optional properties with `string | undefined` type must exactly match a `string | undefined` in the other type. But this is close enough, I think.

Comment: I was just doing the "`A[KA] & B[KB]` should not be `never`" constraint you mentioned in your question.  You can change the constraint if you need to

Comment: I finally got what I'm looking for, thanks to your help. Using `T[K] extends V ? K : never` in KeysWithOverlap, and changing the method to `add<KA extends KeysWithOverlap<A, B[KB]>, KB extends KeysWithOverlap<B, A[KA]>>`, I get the exact solution I was looking for.